# Combinatory Analisis and Newton's Binomial

Tags: trigonometry, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Why is $C_{n}^{0} \ + \ C_{n}^{3} \ +\ C_{n}^{6}\ +\ ...=\ \frac13\cdot[2^n + 2\cdot\cos({\frac{n\pi}3})]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know Newton's binomial expansion formula:
$$(1 + x)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^nC_n^ix^i,$$
then you just apply it to $x = 1, \omega, \omega^2$, where $\omega = \frac{-1 + \sqrt3 i}2$ is a third root of unity.

Adding up the three identities thus obtained (and then dividing by $3$), you will get what you stated in the question.

Comment: Man, I understood this, but I don't know what I have to do in this moment. I have $2^n$, $$(1+\omega)^n=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$$ and $$(1+(\omega)^2)^2=\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right) - i\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)$$

Comment: Just add them up and divide by $3$. This gives you the right hand side of your identity. For the left hand side, write down the three sums and add them up term-by-term.